# Javascript Video player

Tags: javascript, video

When I click the <kbd>Space</kbd> button (break),  it only plays video. It's not stopping with <kbd>Space</kbd>.

I don't know what the problem is.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  const tagName = document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase();

  if (tagName === "input") return;

  switch (e.key.toLowerCase()) {
    case " ":
      if (tagName === "button") return;
    case "k":
      playVideo();
      break;
  }
});
// Play video function
function playVideo() {
  play_pause.innerHTML = "pause";
  play_pause.title = "pause";
  video_player.classList.add("paused");
  mainVideo.play();
}
// Pause video function
function pauseVideo() {
  play_pause.innerHTML = "play_arrow";
  play_pause.title = "play";
  video_player.classList.remove("paused");
  mainVideo.pause();
}

play_pause.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const isVideoPaused = video_player.classList.contains("paused");
  isVideoPaused ? pauseVideo() : playVideo();
});

mainVideo.addEventListener("play", () => {
  playVideo();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is correct answer if someones need.

```js
      case e.keyCode == 32:
        if (mainVideo.paused) {
            mainVideo.play();
        } else {
            mainVideo.pause();
        }
        break;
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
let state = true;
switch (e.key.toLowerCase()) { 
 case e.keyKode == 32: 
 if(state == true){
     playVideo();   
     state = false;
 } else {
   pauseVideo();
   state = true;
 }  
break; 
}
}
```

Try this out for space.

Comment: i do not understand what u mean. sorry. can u give me full code?

Comment: @dokuzor Please edit your answer with this code, and remove it from the comment.

Comment: its working but "k" is starting video and space is stoping. i want to do both with only space. sorry for bad english.

Comment: I changed for both in the source code. If it works without a problem I would like you to choose the correct answer.

Comment: document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  const tagName = document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase();

  if (tagName === "input") return;

  let state = true;
switch (e.key.toLowerCase()) { 
 case e.keyKode == 32: 
 if(state == true){
     playVideo();   
     state = false;
 } else {
   pauseVideo();
   state = true;
 }  
break;

Comment: I don't have your source code etc but according to your given code, I can say that it should work fully otherwise you should check your code again. And try deleting this ```const tagName = document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase(); if (tagName === "input") return```

Comment: i posted full source code

Comment: Thats hard to figure out whats goiong on at only looking that file but remove that code line  ```const tagName = document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase();``` from  document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => { }

Comment: i'm so tired its not working :D